How to deploy a decoupled web application built with .NET Core (.NET 6) for Backend and vanilla html & javascript for Frontend to Azure?
I've built a simple web app using .Net Core (.Net 6) for the backend and vanilla html & javascript in a single "index.html" file in VS Code for the frontend.  I've tested it on my local and everything works as intended.
I'm trying now to deploy it to Azure.  I've deployed the backend successfully, but I'm not sure how to deploy the frontend.  I know how to sign into Azure through VS Code and how to upload my "index.html" to Azure, but I don't know how to make the two parts work together in Azure.  I also don't know if I should upload the index.html file into the same app service or a separate one.
I've searched here on Stack and also on the general Internet a lot for some info on this.  Through this search, I've found basically two methods to do this.  One is to upload the index.html as a "static" file and then make it communicate with my backend using Azure Messaging Service.  The second is to use Docker to create a container that houses both the frontend and the backend and upload the container to Azure.
I would like to get some advice please?

This might be a way

@Jeff you want to deploy the index.html file in the deployed in same .NET core web app or index.html to be deploy separately to another web app?

I would say whichever way is the easiest.  This is only a personal hobby project so there are no hard requirements.  Thanks for your question.

You can deploy your HTML file to static web app and can communicate the backend using API method.
Use fetch to fetch data from backend.
Below are the simple code for my backend webapp and HTML static webapp.
My Backend code :-
HomeController.cs
Its fetching the data from Api https://api.zippopotam.us/us/33162 and returning the value in Json
using html.server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace html.server.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var url = "https://api.zippopotam.us/us/33162";

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0");

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Content(data, "application/json");
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, $"Failed to fetch data from GitHub API.{(int)response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }

}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

My Static Web app :
It will serve my HTML file
Prerequesites :

Github or Azure DevOps require.

To deploy html file follow the steps using Git:

Install Git
Put you html file in new folder.
Run this command to create repository and push the file

git init
git add .               # . to add all file
git commit -m "add Html file"


Install Azure Tools extension
Click on Azure Static web app and select Create Static Web App...



Type your Static web app name  and your GitHub  repo name  whatever you want to keep it.
Select HTML from the option and keep all default for path (/)



I am using the url of my deployed webapp
Index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML-MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi Vivek</h1>
        <button>Get Data</button>
        <div>
            <p> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
            {
                const button = document.querySelector("button")
                const para = document.querySelector("p")
        
                button.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                    fetch('https://webapp12aug.azurewebsites.net/').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{
                        para.innerHTML = `  <ul>
                                               <li>${data['post code']}</li>
                                                <li>${data.country}</li>
                                                <li>${data.places[0]['place name']}</li>
                                                <li>${data.places[0]['state']}</li>
                                            </ul>`
                    })
                })
            }
        </script>
</html>

To Allow CORS
Azure :
Add the url of the static web app in the CORS section of backend web app

Hard code in Porgram.cs
var  builder  =  WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

var  app  =  builder.Build();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");

OUTPUT:
backend data

Static Web App

